# iOS Memory Management & NSString Initialisation

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, nsstring

Still learning iOS development with ObjectiveC and iOS, and trying to realy understand memory management! Appreciate any advise on the snippet below, eg:
1) Analyser says there are potential memory leaks, but can't solve them?
2) Should I keep alloc and init the NSStrings in the for loop and when appended to?

Thanks

```
- (NSString *) lookUpCharNameForID: (NSString *) inCharID
{
    debugPrint ("TRACE", [[@"Lookup Char Name for = " stringByAppendingString: inCharID] UTF8String]);


    NSString *tempName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @""];
    if (![inCharID isEqualToString: @""])
    {
        // Potentially lookup multiple values
        //
        NSString *newName   = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @""];
        NSArray *idList     = [inCharID componentsSeparatedByString: @","];
        for (NSString *nextID in idList)
        {
            NSLog( @"Lookup %i : %@", [idList count], nextID);
            newName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"C%@", nextID];

            // Append strings
            if ([tempName isEqualToString: @""])
                tempName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"%@", newName];
            else
                tempName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"%@+%@", tempName, newName];
        }
        [newName release];
    }

    return [tempName autorelease];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need any of the calls to `alloc`, `release`, or `autorelease`. Instead, use `[NSString stringWithFormat:]` to create instances of `NSString` that you don't own, and therefore don't need to manage. Also, consider using `NSMutableString` to simplify your code a bit, for example along the lines of the following (untested) version:

```
- (NSString *) lookUpCharNameForID: (NSString *) inCharID
{
    NSMutableString *tempName = nil;

    if (![inCharID isEqualToString: @""])
    {
        NSArray *idList = [inCharID componentsSeparatedByString: @","];

        for (NSString *nextID in idList)
        {
            [tempName appendString:@"+"]; // Does nothing if tempName is nil.

            if (tempName == nil)
                tempName = [NSMutableString string];

            [tempName appendFormat:@"C%@", nextID];
        }
    }

    return tempName;
}
```

Comment: Thanks thats a lot lot neater; I did think though that you should use initwithformat but not really understood why

Comment: A call to `alloc` should always be paired with a call to an `init...` method. When you call `alloc` though, you take ownership of the object it returns, and must relinquish ownership eventually by sending the object a `release` or `autorelease` message. It's really helpful to read, or at least skim, Apple's Memory Management Guide to get a more complete picture: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 alloc initWithFormat for tempName.  One before the loop and one within the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Use ARC (Automatic Reference Counting) for new projects.  For older projects it may be easy to convert them, if not ARC can be disabled on a file-by-file basis where necessary.

Using a mutable string, autoreleased convience methods and a little rerfactoring:

```
- (NSString *) lookUpCharNameForID: (NSString *) inCharID
{
    NSMutableString *tempName = [NSMutableArray array];

    if (inCharID.length)
    {
        NSArray *idList = [inCharID componentsSeparatedByString: @","];
        for (NSString *nextID in idList)
        {
            if (tempName.length == 0)
                [tempName appendFormat: @"%@C", nextID];
            else
                [tempName appendFormat: @"+%@C", nextID];
        }
    }

    return tempName;
}
```